# How to optimize this majority vote method

Tags: python, performance, pandas, iterator

I have the following code to do a majority vote for data in a dataframe:

```
def vote(df, systems):
    test = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['begin', 'end', 'case', 'system'])
    n = int(len(systems)/2)
    data = []
        
    for row in test.itertuples():
        # get all matches
        fx = test.loc[(test.begin == row.begin) & (test.end == row.end) & (test.case == row.case)]
        fx = fx.loc[fx.system.isin(systems)]

        # keep if in a majority of systems   
        if len(set(fx.system.tolist())) > n:
            data.append(fx)
             
    out = pd.concat(data, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
    out = out.drop_duplicates(subset=['begin', 'end', 'case'])
    
    return out[['begin', 'end', 'case']]
```

The data look like:

```
systems = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']

df = begin,end,system,case
0,9,A,0365
10,14,A,0365
10,14,B,0365
10,14,C,0365
28,37,A,0366
38,42,A,0366
38,42,B,0366
53,69,C,0366
56,60,B,0366
56,60,C,0366
56,69,D,0366
64,69,E,0366
83,86,B,0367
```

The expected output should be:

```
out = begin,end,case
    10,14,0365
    56,69,0366
```

IOW, if desired elements `begin, end, case` appear in a majority of systems, we accumulate them and return them as a dataframe.

The algorithm works perfectly fine, but since there are hundreds of thousands of rows in it, this is taking quite a while to process.

One optimization I can think of, but am unsure of how to implement is in the `itertuples` iteration: If, for the first instance of a filter set `begin, end, case` there are matches in

```
fx = test.loc[(test.begin == row.begin) & (test.end == row.end) & (test.case == df.case) & (fx.system.isin(systems))]
```

then, it would be beneficial to not iterate over the other rows in the `itertuples` iterable that match on this filter. For example, for the first instance of `10,14,A,0365` there is no need to check the next two rows, since they've already been evaluated. However, since the iterable is already fixed, there is no way to skip these of which I can think.

Comment: Why is `56,69,0366` included in the output? Far as I can tell it occurs only 2 times, same as `38,42,0366` and `56,60,0366`.

Comment: Please do not edit the question after an answer has been given, everyone who sees the question must see the same thing the reviewer than answered saw. Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved with a simple `groupby` operation, which can tell you how often each combination appears. Then you just need to compare this with your `n` and filter the data:

```
key = ["begin", "end", "case"]
n = len(systems) // 2

mask = df.groupby(key)["system"].count() > n

df.set_index(key)[mask] \
  .reset_index() \
  .drop(columns="system") \
  .drop_duplicates()

#    begin  end  case
# 0     10   14  0365
```

This outputs the same as your code on my machine, but not the same as the example output you gave in your question (which I think is wrong).

Note that I used integer division `//` instead of float division `/` and manually casting to `int`.

In general, if you find yourself using `itertuples` in `pandas`, you should think very hard if you cannot achieve your goal in another way, as that is one of the slowest ways to do something with all rows of a dataframe.

Comment: Thanks for confirming! The same solution dawned on me earlier this morning.  (I corrected the example output: I had misread the end value for it!)